# How can I check if a reuse identifier has been registered with a UITableView already?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4

In iOS apps, we have to register nib files with our table view before we can use `UITableView#dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`.

Example:

```
static NSString *myReuseIdentifier = @"MyReuseIdentifier";
UINib *cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:myReuseIdentifier bundle:nil];
[self.tableView registerNib:cellNib forCellReuseIdentifier:myReuseIdentifier];
```

Is there a way to check if a Nib has already been registered with a UITableView?

I have a custom cell that I use in various tables across several controllers in my app. I'd like to move some of the code to a macro. Something like

```
-(CustomCell *)customCell:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    static NSString *reuseIdentifier = @"MyReuseIdentifier";
    if (![table hasAlreadyRegisteredNib:reuseIdentifier]){
       UINib *cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:reuseIdentifier bundle:nil];
       [self.tableView registerNib:cellNib forCellReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];     
    }
    CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just register your nib in the viewDidLoad method?

Comment: Because I would like to stick this in a macro that's shared across several controllers

Comment: But since you have various tables you must register nib for each table.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am not sure if it that what you intend, but

```
-dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:
```

returns `nil` if the cell is not ready to reuse. Otherwise, it returns the cell, so you can simply try.

Comment: Great tip! So I can check if the cell was nil, if so I register the Nib with the table and then return the cell! thanks

Comment: Be careful when depending on nil to register the NIB on iOS 5. There's a bug when VoiceOver is enabled: In this case it always returns nil. So you would end up in an infinite loop registering loop. More details: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13881778/235297

Answer (score 0):

I believe the point of `registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:` is to reduce boilerplate code.  Could you simply call this once in your `viewDidLoad` method?

Comment: I was trying to avoid repeating the same code across multiple controllers - I wrote this as a macro instead