# How to use UINib to instantiate and use custom UITableViewCells

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uikit

how would i use UINibs to instantiate and use a UITableViewCell for a tableview in iOS5.0. I know there is a registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier: in iOS5.0 that also needs to be used, but am not sure how to use it

Thanks in advance for any help on this

Comment: Check out this link: http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2011/2/28/speeding-up-table-view-cell-loading-with-uinib.html That should get you started! :)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

1. Create your xib file with a UITableViewCell as the top-level object. This is called Cell.xib
2. Create a UINib object based on this file
3. Register the UINib with the table view (typically in viewDidLoad of your table view controller subclass).

Steps 2 and 3 can be combined, so you would use the following line in viewDidLoad:

```
[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"Cell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
```

Then, in cellForRowAtIndexPath, if you want one of the cells from the nib, you dequeue it:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
```

This either creates a new instance from the nib, or dequeues an existing cell.

Comment: I actually just implemented the Cell Reuse Identifier myself and it works quite nicely!

Comment: Your solution is absolutely correct but unfortunately there's a bug in iOS 5 (fixed in iOS 6) in conjunction with VoiceOver: http://openradar.appspot.com/11549999

Comment: On loading the cell, I want to customize the background color programmatically (because the bg color is a pattern image). Is it possible?

Comment: @Satyamsvv Yes, use awakeFromNib in the cell subclass. If its more complicated than that, ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

@jrturtons answer is correct but unfortunately there's a bug in iOS 5 (fixed in iOS 6) in conjunction with VoiceOver: [rdar://11549999](http://openradar.appspot.com/11549999). The following category on `UITableView` fixes the issue. Just use `-fixedDequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` instead of the normal `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`. Of course, the NIB must be registered using

```
[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"Cell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
```

before (in `-viewDidLoad`).

**UITableView+Workaround.m:**

```
@implementation UITableView (Workaround)
- (id)fixedDequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier {
    id cell = [self dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
    if (!cell) {
        // fix for rdar://11549999 (registerNib… fails on iOS 5 if VoiceOver is enabled)
        cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:identifier owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    return cell;
}
@end
```

Comment: I've read about this bug a number of times, but have never experienced it — even on iOS 5.0 when running VoiceOver. I believe the actual issue to be far more complicated than this.