# Custom UITabelViewCell subclass initialisation programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

I am working on creating custom `UITableViewCell` with quite a lot of custom elements.
I would like to define everything inside the subclass itself, rather then defining `UIView` inside `tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` function and assigning it to `customCell.contentView`.

What is the best place to setup the cell inside the subclass ?

I ran into small problems trying to set it up inside the `init()`. If I have `self.myTableView.rowHeight = CGFloat(150.0)` setup, then the `self.frame.height` inside `init()` is not `150.0` yet. So this create a problem if I want to use `self.contentView.frame.height` inside my custom `UIView` `CGRectMake` function.

```
class GalleryTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    var galleryCellView:UIView!

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String!) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        println("Init: \(self.frame.height)")
        setupMyCell()
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        println("setSelected \(self.frame.height)")
    }

}
```

Console Output:

```
Init: 44.0
setSelected 150.0
```

So my question - is there a better way to setup custom `UIView` inside `UITableViewCell` subclass ?

Comment: You might be interested in http://stackoverflow.com/a/10533946/2446155

Comment: Xib files look really interesting and I am looking forward to learning them in the near future. At the moment I just want to do it with simple subclass. Cheers for offer !

Comment: If you know the cell will always be 150px tall, just build you view accordingly, Or maybe use Autolayout.