# CollectionView, TableView registered classes for reuse identifiers

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview, reuseidentifier

I want to know which classes are registered with a UITableView or a UICollectionView with reuse identifiers

is it possible to find this info?

I've checked the class references and didn't find anything.

I wanted to unregister certain classes from the tableview in order to replace them with other classes.

I know i can just change the reuse identifier, however, I'd like to know if there is a way to get the registered classes/nibs of these objects

Comment: If only UITableView, take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9829058/how-can-i-check-if-a-reuse-identifier-has-been-registered-with-a-uitableview-alr

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be reuse identifier is married to Registered class when you register a class to tableview.

According to the apple documentation there was no open API to check the registered class. But you can hack like this

```
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)[[self.myTableView visibleCells]lastObject];

//cell.class //Your registered class
```

**You:**
I wanted to unregister certain classes from the tableview in order to replace them with other classes.

```
    - (void)registerClass:(Class)cellClass
      forCellReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier
```

Discussion:

Prior to dequeueing any cells, call this method or the registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier: method to tell the table view how to create new cells. If a cell of the specified type is not currently in a reuse queue, the table view uses the provided information to create a new cell object automatically.

**If you previously registered a class or nib file with the same reuse identifier, the class you specify in the cellClass parameter replaces the old entry**.

OR

**You may specify nil for cellClass if you want to unregister the class from the specified reuse identifier.**

Comment: That hack will not work if the tableview has multiple cell types/identifiers.